# What files can I delete from my project folder?

Tags: unity, publishing

I have a large Unity project and I want to put the source code online. I tried to do it in GitHub but I am out of quota for LFS, so I decided to just zip the project folder and put it on the cloud. Before I do this, I would like to make the folder as small as possible. What files can I delete from the project folder, such that anyone who downloads the remaining files will be able to use my project?

Comment: I can't quite remember the details, but you should be able to delete any saved folders or intermediates for C# database files

Comment: This would also be a good read : http://www.arreverie.com/blogs/unity3d-best-practices-folder-structure-source-control/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard Unity .gitignore file shows what files and folders should not be committed to git and can therefore be deleted.

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore
#
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/[Ll]ogs/
/[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/

# MemoryCaptures can get excessive in size.
# They also could contain extremely sensitive data
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Asset meta data should only be ignored when the corresponding asset is also ignored
!/[Aa]ssets/**/*.meta

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
/[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# Packed Addressables
/[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*

# Temporary auto-generated Android Assets
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa.meta
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa/*
```

The big one is the /Library folder, and of course any folder that contains build outputs.